# ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql

Hello my code is throwing `ClassCastException`.
The StackTrace is showing :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at com.affiliate.DAO.AffiliateDAO.insertAffiliate(AffiliateDAO.java:48)
```

ie @ ***ps.setDate(6, (Date) affiliate.getDate());*** in DAO

**Below is my servlet:**

```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Affiliate af= new Affiliate();

    af.setFisrtName(request.getParameter("txtFname"));
    af.setLastName(request.getParameter("txtLname"));
    af.setGender(request.getParameter("txtGender"));
    af.setCategory(request.getParameter("txtCategory"));
    String dob=(request.getParameter("txtDob"));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
    Date date;
    try {
        date = (Date)formatter.parse(dob);
        af.setDate(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    af.setAge(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtAge")));
    af.setAddress(request.getParameter("txtAddr"));
    af.setCountry("India");
    af.setState(request.getParameter("txtState"));
    af.setCity(request.getParameter("txtCity"));
    af.setPinCode(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtPin")));
    af.setEmailId(request.getParameter("txtEmail"));
    af.setStd(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtStd")));
    af.setContactNo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtPhone")));
    af.setMobileNo(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("txtMobile"),10));

AffiliateService afs=new AffiliateService();
**afs.createAffiliate(af);**
}
```

Below is my DAO:

```
public void insertAffiliate(Affiliate affiliate){
    String sql="INSERT INTO REGISTER " +"(id,FisrtName,LastName,Gender,Category,DateOfBirth,Age,Address,Country,State,City,PinCode,EmailId,Std,ContactNo,MobileNo)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        **conn = dataSource.createConnection();**
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, affiliate.getId());
        ps.setString(2, affiliate.getFisrtName());
        ps.setString(3, affiliate.getLastName());
        ps.setString(4,affiliate.getGender());
        ps.setString(5, affiliate.getCategory());
        ***ps.setDate(6, (Date) affiliate.getDate());***
        ps.setInt(7, affiliate.getAge());
        ps.setString(8, affiliate.getAddress());
        ps.setString(9,affiliate.getCountry());
        ps.setString(10,affiliate.getState());
        ps.setString(11, affiliate.getCity());
        ps.setInt(12, affiliate.getPinCode());
        ps.setString(13, affiliate.getEmailId());
        ps.setInt(14,affiliate.getStd());
        ps.setInt(15, affiliate.getContactNo());
        ps.setLong(16, affiliate.getMobileNo());

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my DTO:

```
public class Affiliate {

@NotNull
    @Past
    Date date;

public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Please help me in this regard

Comment: `new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())`

Comment: To elaborate on @Marko's suggestion, a `java.sql.Date` _is a_ `java.util.Date` - it extends it. The converse it not true; you need to create a `java.sql.Date` from the `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) say, the `Date` parameter in the `setDate()` of `PreparedStatement` takes a Date object of the type `java.sql.Date`. But you seemed to have used `java.util.Date` object in your `Affiliate` class.

And that is why you get the `ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`.

To fix this, you need to either change the type of `Date` object in your `Affiliate` class to `java.sql.Date` or do this

```
ps.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(affiliate.getDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: hey thank u its working but in db its getting stored as yyyy/MM/dd when in SimpleDateFormat ihave converted it into MM/dd/yyyy.So how to get the date in db in the format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: @user3222718 - If you're storing it as a `Date` then its DB dependent. If you're storing it as a String, then you can format it using `SimpleDateFormat` in the format you want and then store it.

Comment: 'String dob=(request.getParameter("txtDob"));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
    Date date;
    try {
        date = (Date)formatter.parse(dob);
        af.setDate(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }'         this is what i did in my servlet which i ve posted in my question.... Please go through and help me i want the db date in the fromat MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: @user3222718 - I say you post this as a new question. AFAIK, if you're storing it as a `Date` directly, then it probably requires DB configuration to store it in the format you want. But the DB format should be irrelevant as whenever you fetch it back from the DB you'll get the `Date` object which doesn't have a format of its own. You can use a SDF on that and format it to any type you want to.

Comment: @user3222718 the date stored in the DB is most likely stored as milliseconds since the epoch, just like a `Date` in Java is. A `String` representation is just that, a representation. When you parse the `String` using your `SimpleDateFormat` you are parsing it _to a `Date`_. In order so view the date in the database, the database also creates a string representation - to make it human readable. Depending on your database this is easily formatted [in much the same way as `SimpleDateFormat` does it.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 7):

`java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, not the other way around.

- `java.sql.Date` can be cast to `java.util.Date`.
- `java.util.Date` **cannot** be cast to `java.sql.Date`.

However, most APIs which sit onto top of JDBC, such as Spring or Hibernate, accept `java.util.Date`. So almost universally, unless you really need a `java.sql.Date`, it is better to import `java.util.Date`.

If using JDBC directly, then for example `java.sql.PreparedStatement` methods only accept `java.sql.Date`, so you will have to construct that yourself.

`java.sql.ResultSet` methods also return `java.sql.Date`, but they can be directly used as a `java.util.Date` without further manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert util date into sql date

```
java.util.Date utilDate = affiliate.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Now, you can insert `sqlDate` as

```
ps.setDate(6, sqlDate);
```

Comment: Rather than just posting the code, try to provide explanation and reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import java.sql.Date`  instead of `import java.util.Date` in your servlet.