# Display Report Parameter in Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm building a report with (*gasp*) `startDate` and `endDate` parameters. **I want to show these parameters in the report.** I've tried a text field with

- `$P{startDate}`
- `"Text"+$P{startDate}`
- `DATEFORMAT($P{startDate},"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

But on every preview attempt I get the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :` error.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

RTFStackTrace.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : DATEFORMAT($P{startDate},"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:467)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$18(ReportControler.java:442)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : DATEFORMAT($P{startDate},"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:611)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:579)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1016)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:573)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:557)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:455)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:433)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:397)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:258)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:124)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:540)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    at MyReportName_282540.evaluate(MyReportName_282540:245)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:250)
    ... 14 more
```

Of note: `java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`

Changing the "Class" option from `java.sql.Date` to `java.util.Date` (as implied by [an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575390/2770309)) let the report run AND showed the value (for every bulleted attempt above).

I promise there was lots of `internet | grep` before this Q&A. From this I'm guessing the `util` form of `Date` is preferred for parameters.